# 2-dimentional lists in python act wierd

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to make a function that rotates a 2-dimentional list in python like so:
input:
`[[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3]]`
output: `[[0,0],[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]`
I wanted to first create a list with placeholder None values so I could easily put in the values later. I came up with this code:

```
matrix = [[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3]]#debugging value, will be an argument of the function. 
output = []
row= []
for x in range(len(matrix)):
    row.append(None)
for x in range(len(matrix[0])):
    output.append(row)
```

So, this creates a nice starting point to now organise the data, but now something weird happens. If I now try to run something like `output[0][0] = 5`, the output variable suddenly has the following values:
`[[5, None], [5, None], [5, None], [5, None]]`, while this line should only affect the first list in the list. Even stranger, now the value of the temporary list row is `[5, None]`. The line should not affect this variable at all. Am I missing something, or is this a bug in Python? I tried this on Python 3.7.6 on windows and Python 3.8.2 on Linux. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: look at the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) builtin function whicch does exactly what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use zip()

```
lst_input=[[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3]]

def rotate_list(lst_input):
    lst_output=[]
    for a,b in zip(lst_input[0],lst_input[1]):
        lst_output.append([a,b])
    return lst_output

print(rotate_list(lst_input))
#[[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
```

Comment: Or just use `list(zip(*lst_input))` (or `list(list(a) for a in zip(*lst_input))` if you are really set on a list of lists).